# Writing BinTree Values in PreOrder in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, tree, preorder

I am Java Beginner and I have a task:
A binary Tree is given and I should write the values of this tree in preorder-traversal in an ArrayList. I have given this method but I am consufsed because the method does not have any parameters. The method is called in an onother class with:

```
tree.toPreOrderList();
```

I thought of the following, but I think it is not correct:

```
    public ArrayList<T> toPreOrderList() {
    ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.set(0, root.getData()); //root is declared abouve as Node<T> root;
    int i = 1;
    while (root.getLeft() != null) {
        list.set(i, root.getLeft().getData());
        i++;
    }
     i++;
    while (root.getRight() != null) {
        list.set(i, root.getRight().getData());
        i++;
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: you already have the instance of the tree, and you are writing a function for it (tree.toPreOrderList();). think of it as writing a print method, only traverse the tree in the order you need.

Answer (score 0):

PreOrder traversal
The meaning of PreOrder traversal is that each node is processed before either of its sub-trees.To simplify, we first visit each node before its children.
Steps for PreOrder traversal are:

1. Visit the node.
2. Traverse the left sub-tree in PreOrder.
3. Traverse the right sub-tree in PreOrder.

There can be two ways of implementing it:

- Recursive
- Iterative

**Recursive:**

```html
 
public void preorder(TreeNode root) {
    if(root !=  null) {
   //Visit the node by Printing the node data  
      System.out.printf("%d ",root.data);
      preorder(root.left);
      preorder(root.right);
    }
  }
```

**Iterative**

```html
public void preorderIter(TreeNode root) {
   
         if(root == null)
             return;
  
         Stack<TreeNode> tree = new Stack<TreeNode>();
         tree.push(root);
  
         while(!stack.empty()){
          
             TreeNode treeNode = tree.pop();
             System.out.printf("%d ",n.data);
  
           
             if(treeNode.right != null){
                 tree.push(treeNode.right);
             }
             if(treeNode.left != null){
                 tree.push(treeNode.left);
             }
  
         }
         
     }
```

Comment: I know these codes, but I cannot transfer them to my case, because i do not have any parameters in the method and I have to write them in an ArrayList...